# How to share the url on a social websites like facebook,google?

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a live stream application.In that I am getting one link.How to share the link on social websites when click on the share button?

Comment: Use the social media platform's *sharing* API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library **[`angular-socialshare`](https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare)**.

Add the references and use it as a dependency,

```
 angular.module('myApp', [
    '720kb.socialshare'
  ]);
```